# When X-ray produced why 99% of the energy is in the form of heat and 1% in the form of X-rays. Why it it not more then that?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, x-rays, experimental-technology

When the electrons hit the anode in an X-ray tube, 99% of their energy is released in the form of heat and 1% of that energy is X-rays. Why it is only 1% and not 2% or 3%?

Comment: Thermionic emission doesn't make x-rays. But if you accelerate electrons to keV energies and then put some matter in the way, you make x-rays. The electron source is often thermionic, but the x-rays don't come from it.

Comment: Are you thinking about an X-ray tube i.e. when electrons strike the target 99% of the KE ends up as heat and only 1% ends up as X-rays? If so this is not _thermionic emission_.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main inefficiencies:

1. Electrons ionize the anode material. This process absorbs most of the energy in the electron beam.
2. The anode material absorbs many of the x-ray photons produced within it.